Internet Browsers become responsive/unresponsive depending on how the dataframe plotted with plotly is constrcucted
I have a dataframe "df" with two columns, time and data, and 600 k rows. Data column contains only integers (1-4 digits with positive and negative values allowed).
I have another dataframe "flags" which is one column and contains either 0 or 3digit values. The numbers in flags are repeating and as such you can find 4-5 different values in them. ie flags.unique returns an array of circa 4-5 values.
I am trying to use plotly for an interactive plot and my browser will react quite differently depending on how the df is treated. I am relatively new in python and as such I am interested to understand why this is happening. By browser I mean firefox, which is my default, but I tried also in Chrome with same results.
Note

I get the plotting result that I want in all situations.
Even though the plotted data are a bit large, they are the same in the working and non-working code

The main difference in the codes I provide is how a fourth column in df, named 'flag_label', is created. Whenever a dictionary is involved then the issues start. However, regardless the method the df is constructed, plotly uses the same df, in the eye at least. So please enlighten me as to what is happening beyond the eye.
# Working Algorithm. Plot in browser is fine and browser does not crush no matter how many graphs I load in the same session.
df = pd.concat([df, flags], axis=1)
df['flag_label'] = df[df.columns[2]].apply(lambda x: f'Flag {x}') #works fine
fig = px.scatter(df, x=df.columns[0], y=df.columns[1], color='flag_label',
                        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8, opacity=0.7), mode='markers')
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Flag #')  
plot(fig) #i have set to 

# Sluggish Algorithm. One plot makes browser slow and unresponsive, eg in firefox 
#Note that I tried with several methods found below commented and all provide unresponsive plots
df = pd.concat([df, flags], axis=1)
value_map = {0: "Invalid", 1: "Valid", 2: "Missing"}
converted_dict = {k: value_map[v[0]] for k, v in original_dict.items()}#look below for the original_dict
color_dict={"Valid": 'black','Invalid': 'red','Missing': 'blue'} 


 #df['flag_label'] = df[df.columns[2]].map(converted_dict) #works but it is very sluggish in plotting
 df['flag_label'] = df[df.columns[2]].apply(lambda x: converted_dict.get(x, None)) #works but it is very sluggish in plotting
 #df['flag_label'] = df[df.columns[2]].replace(converted_dict) #works but it is very sluggish in plotting

fig = px.scatter(df, x=df.columns[0], y=df.columns[1], color='flag_label',
                        color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly)
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=8, opacity=0.7), mode='markers')
fig.update_layout(legend_title_text='Flag #')  
plot(fig) #undocked in editor

To help you out, find below
Example of original dict
orignal_dict = {
    999: [2, "Missing measurement, unspecified reason"],
    990: [2, "Missing due to snow-fall"],
    980: [2, "Missing due to calibration or zero/span check"],
    900: [0, "Hidden and invalidated by data originator"],
    899: [2, "Measurement undefined, unspecified reason"],
    890: [2, "Concentration in precipitation undefined, no precipitation"],
    799: [0, "Measurement missing, data element contains estimated string_flag (invalid)"],
    798: [1, "Measurement missing, data element contains estimated string_flag (valid)"],
    000: [1, "Valid measurement"]
    }

df.head snapshot
flags.head snapshot. It does not only contain zeros, but 699, 559, etc but these are rare

If your data is large and graphs are slow, consider scattergl(). See here in the reference for more information.

I went a bit further. If I create the df using this line of code 'df['flag_label'] = df[df.columns[2]].apply(lambda x: converted_dict.get(x, None))' then it is not working. However if I flag_list = df[df.columns[2]].apply(lambda x: converted_dict.get(x, None)).tolist() #create a list first and then df['flag_label'] = flag_list, which creates the same df but then I have no problem.

This means it is not an issue of large dataset, but rather why plotly deals with the two df differently.
